# Controlling a MIDI Device with Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, midi

I am building a Flutter app that needs to communicate with a Midi Device (Novation Launchpad), so I need dart to be able to receive Midi Input, and also send Mini Output.

I can't find any package with this functionality.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Novation Launchpad too (mk2).
There is one package on pub.dev for another MIDI controller, maybe it can help
https://pub.dev/packages/dart_fire_midi

Also found this GitHub repo

https://github.com/ghost23/windows_midi

But unfortunately last update was year ago.